# Test an infinite loop in minitest

Tags: minitest

I have a job named ActivityJob which fetches an user's github public activities.

```
class ActivityJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :git

  def perform(user)
    begin
      #fetch github activities for a user using user's auth_token
      activities = ActivitiesFetcher.new(user).fetch
      # process the retrieved activities.
    rescue Github::Error::NotFound
      #user is not present. ignore and complete the job.
    rescue Github::Error::Unauthorized
      #auth token is invalid. re-assign a new token on next sign in
      user.auth_token = nil                                                                                                     
      user.save
      # refresh_gh_client gets a new client using a random user's auth_token
      user.refresh_gh_client
      retry
    rescue Github::Error::Forbidden
      # Probably hit the Rate-limit, use another token                                                                          
      user.refresh_gh_client                                                                                                    
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

The method refresh_gh_client gets a random user from db and uses its auth_token to create an new gh_client. the new gh_client is assigned to the current user. This is working fine. In test cases, I am using mocha to stub the method calls.

```
class ActivityJobTest < ActiveJob::TestCase                                                                                       
  def setup                                                                                                                       
    super                                                                                                                         
    @user = create :user, github_handle: 'prasadsurase', auth_token: 'somerandomtoken'                                            
    @round = create :round, :open                                                                                                 
    clear_enqueued_jobs                                                                                                           
    clear_performed_jobs                                                                                                          
    assert_no_performed_jobs                                                                                                      
    assert_no_enqueued_jobs 
  end

  test 'perform with Github::Error::Unauthorized exception' do                                                                    
    User.any_instance.expects(:refresh_gh_client).returns(nil)
  ActivitiesFetcher.any_instance.expects(:fetch).raises(Github::Error::Unauthorized, {})                      
    ActivityJob.perform_now(@user, 'all', @round)                                                                                 
    @user.reload                                                                                                                  
    assert_nil @user.auth_token                                                                                                   
  end
end
```

The problem is that the 'retry' in the job calls the ActivitiesFetcher breaking the expectation that it was supposed to be called only once.

```
:
unexpected invocation: #<AnyInstance:User>.refresh_gh_client()
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, invoked twice: #    <AnyInstance:User>.refresh_gh_client(any_parameters)
- expected exactly once, invoked twice: #<AnyInstance:ActivitiesFetcher>.fetch
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface for the ActivitiesFetcher behavior you need.  You create an implementation of the interface used only for testing that deals with the idiosyncrasies of testing.